# Lambda vs container services?

Tags: serverless, fn

I was wondering since the fn project is based on docker, We can deploy our functions as docker images but this has a handicap... we won't be able to use real lambda functions offer by cloud providers since the moment we will have to use container service.

Even the cost will vary. Am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Fn Project -- https://fnproject.io -- is meant for people that want to run their own functions-as-a-service (FaaS). This gives you a lot of control and no vendor lock-in since you can run it anywhere.

In terms of the containers for your functions, it is correct that you won't be able to run those directly on Lambda. But Fn can run Lambda functions.

And yes, the cost will be different since you'll actually have to run servers to run Fn.

Comment: Thanks Travis for your response,

so in fact there is a serious difference between use this Fn framework and use directly AWS Lambda API...

Which are the advantages of the second one?

I can't see anyone... The usage of AWS Lambda API allow us to really pay what we are using, compute processing (time). With FN we will pay for container registry, server where docker is running and compute processing for our running lambda....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually fn does not only run in one docker container. The fnserver runs in a single container, but it needs to be able to spawn additional containers on-demand, so I do not think it can run on AWS ECS.

If you do not have much fluctuation, but still want to use the advantages of lamdas/functions, you can use self-hosted fnserver and host it on a low-tier server. In the long run this can save some money.

Also if you manage your code in lambda-compatible-functions, you can still self-host them using fn-server, but move to AWS anytime.